# How to read in an array of numbers, split the array in 2, and then find the average of those two separate arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

My program so far asks to input a list of n numbers, then it finds the average of that entire list. How can I split that list in half, and then find the average of the two split up arrays?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int n, i;
    float num[100], sum = 0.0, average;
    printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
        sum += num[i];
    }
    average = sum / n;
    printf("The average is = %.3f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what my code does so far:

```
Enter the total amount of numbers:10  
10   
8  
9   
15  
12    
2  
3  
8  
7  
11  

The average is: 8.500
```

What I want it to do is:

```
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10  
10  
8  
9  
15  
12  
2  
3  
8  
7  
11  

The average of the first half of the array is: 10.8  
The average of the second half of the array is: 6.2
```

Comment: Have two loops, one from 0 to the middle - 1, one from the middle to the end. Each loop takes the average and outputs the average

Comment: Separate the input from the averaging. You don't need two arrays, just examine each half of one array. I can't believe this is a real question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple changing to have array of sum and array of average - each having two members - would do (this way, you only need a single loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int n, i;
    float num[100], sum[2] = {0,0}, average[2]; //have arrays here
    printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

   for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {
      scanf("%f",&num[i]);
      sum[(i*2)/n] +=num[i]; //note the trick here
   }
   average[0]=sum[0]/n;
   average[1]=sum[1]/n;
   printf("The average of the first half of the array is = %.3f\n", average[0]);
   printf("The average of the second half of the array is = %.3f", average[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some compilers require sum[2]={0,0}

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to `sum` and `average` 1/2 your array, all essentially do the same thing in different ways. You can sum/average as you read each 1/2 of the array, or you can wait and iterate of each half at the end to produce the same numbers. You could also separate your array into two separate arrays (which is quite inefficient, since you already have the data in memory, you need only address the values you want to segregate with proper indexing).

Before looking at the ways, there is one improvement you need to make in the way you use `scanf`. All of the `scanf` family members return the total *number of successful conversions* based on the *format-string* you provide. You need to *check the return* and *validate* that you have the number of successful conversions specified in your *format-string*. Always.

One approach to the split is to read all numbers and then iterate over 1/2 the array to get each of the `sum` and `average` values desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, i;
    float num[100], sum[2] = {0.0}, average[2] = {0.0};

    printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {  /* validate your input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf (" enter sum[%2d] ", i);
        if (scanf("%f", &num[i]) != 1) { /* validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* sum/average 1st-half */
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
        sum[0] += num[i];
    average[0] = sum[0] * 2 / n;

    /* sum/average 2nd-half */
    for (i = n/2; i < n; ++i)
        sum[1] += num[i];
    average[1] = sum[1] * 2 / n;

    printf("\nThe 1st-half average is = %.3f\n", average[0]);
    printf("The 2nd-half average is = %.3f\n\n", average[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you do not need to use arrays for `sum` or `average` if you just move your `printf` statements immediately after each calculation).

The second approach uses two loops. The first from `i = 0; i < n/2`, the second from `i = n/2; i < n`. Again, no need for `sum` or `average` arrays if you move the `printf` to immediately following the `sum` and `average` calculations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, i;
    float num[100], sum[2] = {0.0}, average[2] = {0.0};

    printf("Enter the total amount of numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {  /* validate your input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read/sum/average 1st-half */
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; ++i) {
        printf (" enter sum[%2d] ", i);
        if (scanf("%f", &num[i]) != 1) {  /* validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        sum[0] += num[i];
    }
    average[0] = sum[0] * 2/ n;

    /* read/sum/average 2nd-half */
    for (i = n/2; i < n; ++i) {
        printf (" enter sum[%2d] ", i);
        if (scanf("%f", &num[i]) != 1) {  /* validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        sum[1] += num[i];
    }
    average[1] = sum[1] * 2 / n;

    printf("\nThe 1st-half average is = %.3f\n", average[0]);
    printf("The 2nd-half average is = %.3f\n\n", average[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

Either way the resulting output is the same:

```
$ ./bin/array_split
Enter the total amount of numbers: 8
 enter sum[ 0] 1
 enter sum[ 1] 2
 enter sum[ 2] 3
 enter sum[ 3] 4
 enter sum[ 4] 5
 enter sum[ 5] 6
 enter sum[ 6] 7
 enter sum[ 7] 8

The 1st-half average is = 2.500
The 2nd-half average is = 6.500
```

Or, for your example numbers:

```
$ ./bin/array_split
Enter the total amount of numbers: 10
 enter sum[ 0] 10
 enter sum[ 1] 8
 enter sum[ 2] 9
 enter sum[ 3] 15
 enter sum[ 4] 12
 enter sum[ 5] 2
 enter sum[ 6] 3
 enter sum[ 7] 8
 enter sum[ 8] 7
 enter sum[ 9] 11

The 1st-half average is = 10.800
The 2nd-half average is = 6.200
```